# Client Side Validation with WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to perform client side validation on my objects that come back through WebApi. I send the entity through webapi to my Entity edit screen. I use knockout to bind the object to the fields.

I already have an action filter handling all the server side validation.
How could I incorporate the client side validation without having to duplicate my domain model data annotations?

Answer (score 1):

With WebApi, you need a little “glue” code to connect the errors coming back from model validation failures to the client side validator.

```
function extractErrors(jqXhr, validator) {
    var data = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText), // parse the response into a JavaScript object
        errors = {};

    $.each(data.ModelState, function (key, value) {
        var pieces = key.split('.');
        key = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
        errors[key] = value
    });

    validator.showErrors(errors); // show the errors using the validator object
}
```

On the model, annotate as usual:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Group Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In the view, add the ValidationMessageFor tags:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Phillip. This still requires a server side round trip before any validation is shown to the user. Take the [Required] attribute, you wont see it added to your errors variable until it fails at the server. Unless I have misunderstood your solution, or epicly failed at explaining my problem.

Comment: True, it does post the values to the server, and gets back a string of json.
In my case, my forms were not huge, so I got client side “like” performance, and client side “like” behavior, no obvious post backs.  On a small form with 10 valdations, the server trip cost:
1/100th of a sec locally hitting dev server.
1/10th of a sec hitting an AWS cloud server from corporate LAN.
This was for a corporate LOB type app, probably not appropriate for mobile/slow connections.
In my case, controlling validation by annotating the model was worth the trip, and made development cleaner and quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, it is actually quite helpful. Unfortunately some of our forms can be quite complex (e.g. 50-100 form fields worst case scenario, as we are developing a transactional finance system), probably not the best design, but our business is dictating this. We are getting approx 300-400ms rount trip to Azure.

Comment: Any chance you can compress the JSON?  Watch traffic in Fiddler, it may already be compressed. If not, check out http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I create my HTTP API, I put the model objects (DTOs, request models, etc) into a separate  assembly which I can distribute for .NET clients.

Consider the following class:

```
public abstract class UserUpdateRequestModel {

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(320)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I use in my API:

```
public UserDto PutUser(Guid key, UserUpdateRequestModel requestModel) {

    // Do something here
}
```

You can use this same model in your ASP.NET MVC client application for example to generate the HTML inputs with validation `data-` attributes as ASP.NET MVC has a way of generating those based on data annotation validation attributes.

Comment: So you would add some sort of metadata object (which would contain the validation attributes) to the webapi response? How would you go about creating the client side code?

Comment: @kpore if you are going to use ASP.NET MVC, it has a way of creating those. For example with `TextBoxFor` html helper method. Have a look: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually am not using MVC. I am using WebApi for all of my communication and persistence. HTML Helpers are only for when you are using classic MVC controllers.