# ASP.NET Web API 2 - Ajax Post JQuery Unobtrusive Validation Errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have the following form inside a bootstrap modal which I submit via ajax to a web api controller. If the model state is invalid I want to display the errors beneath the input fields. I have the htmlhelper  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)` defined but the message does not appear there?

```
<form id="form1" method="post">

           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

           <button type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    $("#form1").submit(function() {

            if (!$(this).valid()) {
               return false;
            }  

            $.post(baseUrl + "api/somecontroller", $('#form1').serialize())
                .done(function (data) {
                   // do some stuff

                   // hide modal
                   $('#form1').modal('hide');
                })
                .fail(function (jqXhr) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText), errors = {};

                    $.each(data.ModelState, function (key, value) {
                        var pieces = key.split('.');
                        key = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
                        errors[key] = value;
                    });

                    validator.showErrors(errors);
                });
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

in the jqxhr.responseText I get the following:

```
{
   "message": "The request is invalid.",
   "modelState": {
     "person.Name": [
      "The Name field is required."
      ]
    }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

Using the code from the following link [Client Side Validation with WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945688/client-side-validation-with-webapi)

I now get error: `validator is not defined`

Also the form doesn't seem to validate before I call the ajax post method despite calling the following:

```
if (!$(this).valid()) {
    return false;
}
```

Note I'm using this Web Api inside and MVC project.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945688/client-side-validation-with-webapi

Comment: @stephen.vakil I've tried the code from the link you have posted but I now get error `validator is not defined` -  see my updated code.

Comment: Are you using unobtrusive validation and/or jquery validation?

Comment: @stephen.vakil it will be unobtrusive validation which comes out of the box with asp MVC

Comment: You have to get the validator using something like  `var validator = $("#form").validate();`  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/

Comment: @stephen.vakil Thanks that works. There was also a typo in `data.ModelState` which should have been `data.modelState` which meant  no errors were being added to the errors array.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Is there any way to validate the form before doing the ajax post? I've added the following : `if (!$(this).valid()) {    return false;  } ` before the ajax method and nothing seems to happen i.e. no errors are displayed - see updated code.

Comment: @adam78, you are supposed to call `validate` before `valid`. *".valid(): Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid."* *"validate() needs to be called on the form before checking it using valid() method."*

Comment: @derloopkat unobtrusive validation works differently. The problem was I hadn't applied the data annotations to the model being passed to the view. It works now after applying the data annotations.